# retrieving value via SQLDataReader.get_Item()

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to access external sql-tables via the following code. Accessing works as intended, but I have problems to process the values, if datatype has to be casted for futher processsing.

The following code can be executed as job in ax:

```
static void Job1(Args _args)
{
    str serverName;
    str catalogName;
    str ConnectionString;
    str sqlQuery;

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection parameterCollection;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dataReader;
    ;
    new InteropPermission( InteropKind::ClrInterop ).assert();

    sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM PRODROUTE";

    serverName = SysSQLSystemInfo::construct().getLoginServer();
    catalogName = SysSQLSystemInfo::construct().getloginDatabase();
    connectionStringBuilder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connectionStringBuilder.set_DataSource(serverName);

    connectionStringBuilder.set_IntegratedSecurity(true);
    connectionStringBuilder.set_InitialCatalog(catalogName);
    ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.get_ConnectionString();

    connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlQuery);
    command.set_Connection(connection);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while(dataReader.Read())
            {
                //info( dataReader.get_Item( "PRODID" )); // ok
                //info( dataReader.get_Item( "LEVEL" )); // not working
                info ( int2str( dataReader.GetInt32( 23 ))); // not working
                //info( any2str(dataReader.get_Item( "LEVEL" ))); // not working
            }
            dataReader.Dispose();
        }
        catch 
        {
            dataReader.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception::CLRError)
        {
            dataReader.Dispose();
        }
        connection.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception::CLRError)
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
    command.Dispose();
    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
}
```

There are four codelines to access data:

```
//info( dataReader.get_Item( "PRODID" )); // ok
//info( dataReader.get_Item( "LEVEL" )); // not working
info ( int2str( dataReader.GetInt32( 23 ))); // not working
//info( any2str(dataReader.get_Item( "LEVEL" ))); // not working
```

As you see, only one line won't throw an error, since datatype of field fits to the desired operation. Info-logging is just an example. If I try to assign data to ax-table-fields, the same problem occurs.
Casting via `int2str()`, `any2str()` and so on doesn't work as well.

So what's the right way to handle data read, for further processing?

**@edit:** ErrorMsg

Fehler während der Verarbeitung: Elementtyp für Variablenzuweisung ungültig.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Is `dataReader.get_Item( "LEVEL" ))` not getting data, or is passing that as a parameter to `info()` telling you it's not a string?

Comment: Of course, I'm getting data. I've edited OQ and added errorLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried running your query directly in SSMS, and found that the field LEVEL didn't exist on the actual table on sql server, but there is a field named "LEVEL_" (which is the 3rd field on my table).

Additionally, this talks about any2str not doing what you would expect it to do, but I don't think that is your problem on retrieving the LEVEL field.
http://abraaxapta.blogspot.com/2012/02/kernel-function-madness-any2str.html

Comment: You're right. Seems it was a lucky shot by myself to chose exactly **this** field for testing... NOT. Funny, it is named "LEVEL" without underscore in the AOT. Adding the underscore made it work. Thanks for the hint! Debugged at wrong place :/